# How can I see what URL Guzzle is reporting data from?

Tags: php, guzzle

I am *very* new to using Guzzle, and my php feet are still quite soft. Nevertheless, I found Guzzle to be quite forgiving. I followed the following example, tweaking here and there:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Pool;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$requests = function ()
{
    ...[generate url]..

    yield $index => new Request('GET', $theURL);
};

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests(), [
    'concurrency' => 50,
    'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index)
    {
        $content = $response->getBody()
                            ->getContents();

        file_put_contents('storage/' . $index, $content);

        print 'fulfilled index:' . $index . PHP_EOL;
    },
    'rejected' => function ($reason, $index)
    {
        print 'rejected index:' . $index . PHP_EOL;
    },
]);

$promise = $pool->promise();

$promise->wait();
```

This works well, but there is a case in which I need to know the URL. It's failing, but I cannot tell /which/ of the 1000 URLs I am feeding it is failing. I can see the 'index', but I cannot understand how to use the index to tell me something meaningful (specifically, the URL).

`var_dump( $response );` shows me the response but not the URL.
`var_dump( $index );` shows me an index, in this case `int(1100)`, but I've no clue how to use that to my benefit.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: You would need to associate the `$index` with `$theURL`, your not currently doing that your associating the Request with it. In the section `..[generate url]..` do the association and use a use, e.g `$requests = function () use (&$urls)` to maintain a state, which you can then pass to all your closures.

Comment: For example: https://3v4l.org/mU1IX